# How to save audio file with AudioKit?

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I have audio file. I made some effects on it

```
let pitchshifter = AKPitchShifter(self.audioPlayer)
pitchshifter.shift = 10
AudioKit.output = pitchshifter
```

It works if I play it in app, but I want to save it as a new file to use it as avasset later. How it can be implemented?

I tried using AKNodeRecorder but this produces empty audio track:

```
let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("recorded")
let format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat64, sampleRate: 44100, channels: 2, interleaved: false)!
let tape = try! AKAudioFile(forWriting: url, settings: format.settings)
let mixer = AKMixer(self.audioPlayer!, pitchshifter)
AudioKit.output = mixer
self.recorder = try! AKNodeRecorder(node: mixer, file: tape)

try? AudioKit.start()
self.audioPlayer?.play()
self.audioPlayer?.completionHandler = {
    self.recorder?.stop()
    self.selectedAudioURL = tape.url
}
```

Also I tried renderToFile method - it is also not working [and I got this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZQMl.png)

```
let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("recorded.m4a")
let format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat64, sampleRate: 44100, channels: 2, interleaved: false)!
let tape = try! AKAudioFile(forWriting: url, settings: format.settings)
try! AudioKit.renderToFile(tape, seconds: Double(CMTimeGetSeconds(self.selectedAudioAsset!.duration)))
```

That's how I add initial file to AudioKit:

```
let audioFile = try AKAudioFile(forReading: audioURL, commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, interleaved: true)
let player = AKPlayer(audioFile: audioFile)
self.audioFile = audioFile
self.audioPlayer = player
player.startTime = self.startTime
AKSettings.defaultToSpeaker = true
```

Thanks in advance for the answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I found, you have to use the prerenderer to "play" what you want to record:

```
try AudioKit.renderToFile(outputFileForWriting, duration: sequencerTotalSeconds, prerender: {
    self.sequencer.play()
})
```

But, for me.. Rendering out a single track sequence produces a sinus sound. :-/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
Just added self.player.play() in prerender block and it worked!

Comment: @August any solution for silent sound?

Comment: From what I remember, the code base was transitioning to using new type of output.. And, I think it was in progress -- after that I am not sure

Comment: Might be able to dig some info from their issues on 'render' : https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/issues?utf8=✓&q=is%3Aissue+render+