# AudioKit renderToFile doesn't work

Tags: audiokit

I am trying to load a song, mix it with filters and save it to file. However I cannot manage to get it work with AudioKit.renderToFile. I always get "no such file" after rendering.

My code is very similar [to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50590012/how-to-save-audio-file-with-audiokit).

```
if let fileUrl = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "song", ofType: "wav") {
    export()
}
```

Rendering:

```
func export(songUrl: String) {
    do {
        if let url = URL(string: songUrl) {
            if let file = try? AKAudioFile(forReading: url) {
                player = try AKAudioPlayer(file: file)
            }
        }
    } catch {
        fatalError("PLAYER URL ERROR")
    }

    mainMixer = AKMixer(player)
    AudioKit.output = mainMixer

    do {
        try AudioKit.start()
        self.outputFile = try AVAudioFile(forWriting: exportURL, settings: player.audioFile.fileFormat.settings)
        try AudioKit.renderToFile(self.outputFile, duration: self.player.duration, prerender: {
            self.player.play()
        })
    } catch {
        fatalError("Unexpected error: \(error).")
    }

    self.showFileSize()
}
```

Export URL:

```
let exportURL: URL = {
    let documentsURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory
    return documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("exported_song.wav")
}()
```

showFileSize uses FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: filePath) but here it throws an exception:

```
The file “exported_song.wav” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.
```

What I am doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I ran the sample project this programmer so graciously created for me to test with and I can tell that a file is definitely being created. Why iOS is not seeing it could be related to sandboxing perhaps?

Comment: @AureliusProchazka You are right - the problem is with reading. I commited 2 changes on test project: 1) I check file with `FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url)` 2) I load data `let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: url))` 3) I try to play `audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: url))`.
1) and 2) works OK so the file is created but AVAudio cannot load it. I also tried init with AVAudio(data) but it also throws error. I even added option to share data file - and when i opened it and renemed on Mac - the sound is good (with all effects).

Comment: @AureliusProchazka I think that there also may be something wrong with renderToFile. I printed AudioFile.fileFormat from resources: `<AVAudioFormat 0x6000000991e0:  2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'alac' (0x00000003) from 24-bit source, 4096 frames/packet>`
But from documents after render it looks like this: `<AVAudioFormat 0x604000097890:  2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'alac' (0x00000000) from UNKNOWN source bit depth, 0 frames/packet>`

source bit is UNKNOWN and there are 0 frames/packet. Do you know what may be the issue?

Comment: @AureliusProchazka I finally managed to get it work but it's not very trivial. What I did (accidentally) was to create output file and renderToFile twice. I updated test project so you can test it. In SongPlayer -> export method. Normally creating AVAudioPlayer or any other approach to create audio file/asset failed. Now after second render it works.. What may be interesting - I am printing file size and I can see that after first render it is (in bytes): 13857770 but after second: 13857778. So these additional 8 bytes must be doing "the job".

Comment: @AureliusProchazka If you could analyze it and give your thoughts we will be able to create sample project and maybe marge it into your docs as IMO it was missing.

Comment: @AureliusProchazka Do you have any idea why it has to be done twice? https://gist.github.com/Ufosek/0631189e41663cf11585fb732353cc53

Comment: No I don't know why it works on the second time, perhaps there's a race condition that the first process delays the second one to be successful.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me to write a *.wav file output (ends up in Documents/out.wav):

```
private func testRecord() {
    let testOscillator = AKOscillator()
    AudioKit.output = testOscillator

    // write to file
    do {
        try AudioKit.start()

        print("home: \(NSHomeDirectory())")

        guard let outURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first?.appendingPathComponent("out.wav") else {
            fatalError("Failed URL create")
        }

        guard let format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatInt16, sampleRate: 44100, channels: 2, interleaved: true) else {
            fatalError("Failed to create format")
        }

        let file = try AKAudioFile(forWriting: outURL, settings: format.settings)

        try AudioKit.renderToFile(file, duration: 10.0, prerender: {
            testOscillator.start()
        })
    } catch {
        print("renderToFile error: \(error)")
    }
    print("didn't crash")
}
```